# Не скрываются посты в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: wordpress

Возникла проблема со скрытием постов из определенной категории на главной странице.Сайт -https://fsledokol.ru
Если точнее, то посты скрываются только на десктопной версии, а на мобильной отображаются. Для реализации использовался код:

```
function removeFromHome($query) {
if ($query->is_home) {$query->set('cat','-22,-24,-23');

} return $query;

}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','removeFromHome');
```

Видимо у сайта есть ещё одна версия главной страницы рассчитанная на мобильные устройства. Подскажите, как доработать скрипт, чтобы посты скрывались и на телефонах.

Comment: Не знаю где у тебя мобильная версия, но адаптива там нет и вообще ахтунг https://i.imgur.com/6Fvbrm5.jpg

Comment: Ааа, по UA определяется и включается мобильная тема. В шаблонах значит ищи. Но ещё лучше - выкинуть это всё и переделать.